# Why does the Facebook ApplicationId need a space in front of the number in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml, facebook

When an Android app uses Facebook, if the app ID is included in AndroidManifest.xml (EDIT: it turns out this is not recommended), the value needs to have a space as its first character, escaped with a backslash like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 00000"/>
```

My question is, why is that backslash-escaped space needed there?

Is it a hurdle put there to make you think about what you are doing when you put a value in there? Is it there to make sure that some parser treats it as a string rather than a decimal number?

Comment: You may want to use an @string value rather than hardcoded text. It'll take care of that problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll actually add an answer so it can be accepted. Best practice is to use an @string value.

In your strings.xml add:

```
<string name="app_id">123456789</string>
```

Then, in your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Comment: Good to know. That suggests that my second guess is near the mark? (leading space causes parsers to infer `string` rather than `integer`)

Comment: After some research, I would say that's a pretty accurate guess. I couldn't find any hard and fast rules on xml parsing, and how conversions work (implicit vs. explicit), but I would say you're on the right track.